# Unzip file without exhausting stream

Tags: c#

I have written a tool that downloads a zipfile from one endpoint and uploads to another. While doing this I use cryptostream to calculate the md5sum of the file. This is done passively, so it is first when the stream is exhausted by the sender that the md5sum is calculated.

Can I do the same, but for inspecting the zip file? What I would like is to get a callback when each file is encountered in the stream so I can choose to save it or not. But I do not want to keep the entire zip file or it's contents in memory or disk, as large files are involved.

So in short, I want this:

- Stream from HTTP GET
- Calculate md5sum as stream is traversed
- Unzip selectively as stream is traversed
- POST stream to destination endpoint.

Comment: You basically can't do this because the ZIP file format doesn't support it. The ZIP central directory is at the end. An unreliable approach is to scan for the local file signatures -- this is unreliable because it can fail for nested ZIP files, custom data inbetween file entries or files updated/appended after the archive was initially created.

Comment: That's it. A zip archive can't be unpacked while streaming (cause the archive content information is at the end of the file). Unzip a zip stream of a single file (or content) is possible (and a lot of web clients and servers support this via header information _gzip_, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding#directives).

Comment: Thanks. The fact that you can unzip a file from a stream made me assume that it could be read beginning to end without needing to traverse the entirety of the stream (ie. seeking to the end for the index) before deflating.

Comment: It is a bit of a messy subject. If you read the documentation for the zip format: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT you will find several references to streaming access - and warnings for when it will not work (encryption, replace/delete files by appending to the file only for example). If your source files did not do any of those - yes, the format supports streaming access and was intended to do so.